# Running time of a modified merge sort compared to merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, computer-science, mergesort

From wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#Application

In the diagram, let's say we consider the middle row of numbers (would help if someone can post the picture here). What would the running time of the algorithm be if I modified it to:

- Merge 38 and 27, then sort the numbers in ascending order. (27, 38)
- Merge the result from above with 43, then sort the numbers in ascending order. (27, 38, 43)
- Merge the result from above with 3, then sort the numbers in ascending order. (3, 27, 38, 43).
- ...And so on until I have a fully sorted list.

This is an EXTREMELY inefficient way to sort (I can tell intuitively - in the worst case the number being added would swap with every number in the list) though I'm not so sure how it compares (in terms of justifying my analysis) to Merge Sort's O(n log n) time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you’re describing is insertion sort - you’re building a growing list of values in sorted order by adding one element in at a time. That means the runtime matches insertion sort - linear if the array is sorted, quadratic on average, etc.